# How to I create a MainWindow.xib in Xcode 4.2 in an iOS application?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am just starting out learning to build interfaces, but the book I am following is a little dated and it says that Xcode should create it for me with my new project, however it didn't. So now I need to link my buttons to my app delegate, but I can't because it isn't showing up when I right click on my buttons. And yes, I did define my methods and instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode very much will create a MainWindow.xib *if you choose Cocoa Application as the project type.*  Check to make sure you aren't either creating an iOS project or a command-line tool... both can be easy to accidentally select when you are just starting to learn.

(FYI, I just verified in Xcode 4.2.1 that a MainWindow.xib was created for me.)

Comment: Ah whoops, that was the problem. So now I have a small side question. The book I am using is a tutorial for iOS, and that is what I meant (was in a bit of a rush so I forgot to add that). Does iOS still offer the MainWindow.xib? Or is it different now (this book is iOS 4, not iOS 5, it is a year old).

Comment: Ah.  No, MainWindow.xib is not needed anymore (strictly speaking, it wasn't ever *needed*).  You just create views for view controllers.  There is a UIWindow method (setRootViewController:) that is used as part of the bootstrapping process to make this all work, but you needn't worry about this if you are just beginning.  Use any of the non-empty project templates and just modify the .xibs that Xcode will create and hook up automatically for you.

Comment: Also, really, get a newer book.  Both Xcode and the APIs have changed quite a bit in the recent past, and you don't want to have to deal with this kind of ongoing frustration.  $30 will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: What would you recommend? I am moving from the Big Nerd Ranch Programming Objective-C to their iOS Programming book, but their new book revision is not due out till March.

Comment: @Dave Too bad... maybe try to get an advance copy?  I'm a big fan of BNR's books.  I've also heard good things about Matt Neuburg's iOS book, and he contributes a lot to the cocoa-dev mailing list, so you could take questions right to the source. :-)